# Jekyll - Main sass and index files replaced after bundle exec Jekyll serve

Tags: github, jekyll, bundle

I am trying to create a Jekyll site, nothing too complicated. I want to update the css to use sass and have 'main.css' that includes @imports to include the various other sass files I have created in the _sass folder.

I have followed the https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll-sass-converter/tree/master/docs simple example and every time I run the 'bundle exec jekyll serve' command to test the new styles I have added. The styles are overridden by deleting whatever is in the assets/css/ are with the default style.css

I have tried everything including --clean and --redownload with bundle install but it keeps overriding my styles and the index.html to a previous version.

Please see the attached screenshot below for my Gemfile and _config.yml

[image]